# What does comma do with dict.keys() when assigning variables?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a newbie question regarding the usage of comma (,) when trying to get the key from a dictionary. I checked Python 3.7 documentation,and several other sites but couldn't find the answer.

I have a simple dictionary with one element in it:

```
basket = {'apple':1}
```

I want to get string `'apple'` from it. 
If I do:

```
k = basket.keys()
print(k)
```

I get

```
dict_keys(['apple'])
```

If I do:

```
k, = basket.keys()
print(k)
```

I get

```
apple
```

So why do I need the comma to get the string `'apple'`?

Comment: Because the method is `keys()`, plural; it returns a collection of keys. It so happens that your dict only has one key, but it still returns a collection.